# Send a message to a channel using a command discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a `-say #channel-name message` command for my discord bot using the code:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def say(self, ctx, channel, *, message):
    channel = discord.
    await channel.send(message)
```

And got an error
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: CommandAttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'`
As far as I'm aware, this code is correct and should be able to send a message to the channel mentioned, but it does not and throws the error instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to send a message to the channel the command was executed in, or a user-specified channel?

Comment: What is `discord.`? You can probably just remove that channel parameter completely and change the bottom line to `await ctx.send(message)`. Unless the channel parameter is meant to be inputted by the user to direct the output message to another channel than the one it was used in?

Comment: if you want the user to define the channel themselves, use this: `discord.utils.get(self.get_guild(ctx.guild.id).channels, name=channel)` also check your indentation. it looks improper here but maybe it's correct in your actual script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `channel` is of type `str`, not `discord.TextChannel`. To convert it to a channel you can do `channel : discord.TextChannel` in the arguments:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def say(self, ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel, *, message):
    channel = discord.
    await channel.send(message)
```